# IOS launch app from background

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, restart

I want to test the crash analytics automatically that an IOS app can crash and restart repeatedly and automatically. I first launch an keep alive app using the URL scheme to launch the crash test app periodically. After a while the crash test app crashes, but the keep alive app is running in background that it can not launch the crash app though it's still running.
Is there any solutions to repeatedly restart an app in IOS?

Help will be much appreciated :)
Thanks for your time,
Linson